# MySQL service stopping

Tags: raspbian, mysql

I've had a couple of web apps running on my Raspberry Pi (lighttpd, PHP, MySQL) and have notice recently that the MySQL service dies or stops about once a week.

I've checked the MySQL logs under /var/log but they are either empty or give no clues why the daemon is stopping.
Restarting the MySQL service brings the databases back up okay.

Anybody else seen this behavior?

Apps I am running are Piwigo and Tiny Tiny RSS.

Comment: Add following directives to /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql daemon. Then try again to inspect the log file. #general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like MySQL is running out of memory.

Have you checked the kernel log to see if the process is being terminated there?

```
/var/log/kern.log
```

You may need to tweak the setting in the my.cnf file:

```
 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: Logging to the system log which had out of memory errors. Changed the memory gpu split to free up some memory. Will have a look at the config tweaking.

Comment: Been a lot more stable since I reduced the memory to the GPU.